# Creating a Java.util.List from an existing .txt file 'FIXED'

Tags: java, list, text-files, file.readalllines

I'm trying to create a java.util.List from an existing .txt file, when the list is created and filled with the java.util.String from the .txt file I would like to print it to the console to test if the List is filled. I have tried a lot but I always keep getting the same error.

The layout of the project is as following: Module (QaA), src(WriteTest.java and testfile.txt).

The testfile.txt contains the following:

Sentence one testing
Sentence two testing
Sentence three testing
Sentence four testing

the WriteTest Class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files; 
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;


public class WriteTest {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Path testPath = Paths.get("src/testfile.txt");

    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(testPath);

        for (String line : lines) {
            System.out.println(line);   
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The following errors are received:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: src\testfile.txt
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
at java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(Files.java:2784)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3202)
at java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines(Files.java:3242)
at WriteTest.main(WriteTest.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

I have found another reason why I had loads of errors. The location of my .txt file should not have been within the src. I tried moving it out, parallel to my module, and there it was detectable.

Comment: Post the error stacktrace please

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari With such code, probably a `FileNotFoundException`

Comment: Hint : use `System.out.println(Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath());` in order to know where you are when searching files with a relative path.

Comment: Try passing only file name i.e. Paths.get("testfile.txt");

Comment: I tried changing the Paths to Paths.get("testfile.txt") which ended up giving me the same erros.

Comment: Put the .txt file parallel to your class file, i.e. .java file

Comment: @HimanshuBhandari I tried that, still received the same errors

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You called it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code had error on my workspace, I changed the readAllLines as you see below, and added toAbsolutePath for the path

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    Path testPath = Paths.get("src/testfile.txt").toAbsolutePath();
    System.out.println("path:\t" + testPath);
    try
    {
        Charset cs = Charset.defaultCharset();
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(testPath, cs);

        for (String line : lines)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This indeed gave me the absolutePath. I still got an error when trying to print it in the console, but I managed to place the output from the textfile into a screen. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make the changes as below to get the given file path.

```
Path testPath = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"src/testfile.txt");
```